# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey -servlet threw exception

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, jersey

Please help me guys..I am running a simple maven project on tomcat and i am getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115) 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:6java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
 com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
```

My java file is :

```
package com.mysterious;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {

@GET
 @Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsgWithParam(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
    String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}

@GET
public Response getMsg() {
    String output = "Welcome to WebService";
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

}

Web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.mysterious</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.XML

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mysterious</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestWs</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RestWs Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>RestWs</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is the url you are trying ? Also, I don't see any reference of jersey bundle.

Comment: I am trying : localhost:8080/RestWs/hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pom.xml`, you didn't included jersey. You need to add jersey to your dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And url should be

```
localhost:8080/RestWs/hello/yourname
```

Comment: I have added given dependency and tried url also .. not working :( giving same error.. is there any error in my java or web.xml file ?

Comment: @AltamashAli did you removed other dependencies ?

Comment: no.. which dependency do i have to remove ? i have just added above dependency

Comment: @AltamashAli just keep, which I mentioned and remove all. Also, remove `getMsg` method from your code.

Comment: @AltamashAli You shouldn't get same error, did you refresh maven ?

Comment: yeah i have refreshed it...by clean install and again running on localhost

Comment: @AltamashAli I really doubt that, but anyway, is `RestWs` your application name ? And are you sure, you are exactly same error ? not even slight difference ?>

Comment: yes sir i am getting the same error no difference ... nd yeah application name is RestWs

Comment: @AltamashAli As I mentioned, I don't see any issue now, could create new project with same details ? and let me know ?? Just in case, try this `mvn clean install -U` also.

Comment: ok sir.. i will try this command and  will tell u... or by creating new project ... Thank you so much   for ur help :)

Comment: I have tried 'mvn clean install -u' ... now i am getting error message as "The requested resouce is not available"

Comment: @AltamashAli As said, you were not cleaning it correctly. What is the url are u trying

Comment: URL  "localhost:8080/RestWs/hello/ali"

Comment: i have tried this in same old project ... now i will try in new project ... and will tell u

Comment: @AltamashAli wait.. can take the screenshot of your project and post ??

Comment: do i have to send u code screenshot or project structure ?

Comment: @AltamashAli open `HelloService` file and take complete scrnsot includes project structure

Comment: @AltamashAli I don't see any issue, can you create new project and try ?

Comment: I have created new project and run it again...but got same error as "Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] threw exception"

Comment: @AltamashAli You shouldn't. You are doing something wrong. I can't tell it from here. Just think this way, You had same project which was giving same error while ago and you corrected something and you got resource error. Now, you created new project with corrected details. You shouldn't get same error which you were getting initially. If you are getting means you are n't doing correctly

Comment: Link to  new project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zc5o290yfcnevs3/RestApp.rar?dl=0

Comment: sir can u check this once .. i have sent u link to the project

Comment: @AltamashAli Why do you have `javaee-web-api` in your dependencies ?

Comment: it will give error in java file if i dont add that dependency as cant find javax.ws.rs

Comment: @AltamashAli No,  they shouldn't be included and `jersey-server` should be enough. Instead you can include this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.0

Comment: But I am getting error in index.jsp that the superclass "javafx.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the java build path

Comment: @AltamashAli Do one thing, just download and open example project and run http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/. It is very difficult to debug something, which you haven't written.